# Pandas [.dt] property vs to_datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime, datetime-format

**The question is intended to build an understandable grasp on subtle differences between `.dt` and `pd.to_datetime`**

I want understand which method is suited/preferred and if one can be used as a defacto and other differences that are there between the two

```
values = {'date_time':  ['20190902093000','20190913093000','20190921200000'],
          }
          
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = ['date_time'])

df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

>>> df
            date_time
0 2019-09-02 09:30:00
1 2019-09-13 09:30:00
2 2019-09-21 20:00:00
```

> Using .dt

```
df['date'] = df['date_time'].dt.date

>>> df
            date_time        date
0 2019-09-02 09:30:00  2019-09-02
1 2019-09-13 09:30:00  2019-09-13
2 2019-09-21 20:00:00  2019-09-21

>>> df.dtypes
date_time    datetime64[ns]
date                 object
dtype: object

>>> df.date.values
array([datetime.date(2019, 9, 2), datetime.date(2019, 9, 13),
       datetime.date(2019, 9, 21)], dtype=object)
```

Using `.dt` , even though the elements are individually `datetime` , is inferred as `object` in the 'DataFrame` , **which sometimes is suited** but mostly its causes a lot of problems down the line and an  implicit conversion is inevitable

> Using pd.to_datetime

```
df['date_to_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')

>>> df.dtypes
date_time           datetime64[ns]
date                        object
date_to_datetime    datetime64[ns]

>>> df.date_to_datetime.values
array(['2019-09-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-09-13T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-09-21T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Using `pd.to_datetime` , natively returns a `datetime64[ns]` array and inferred the same in the `DataFrame` , which in my experience is consistent and widely used , when dealing with `dates` using pandas

I m aware of the fact a native `Date` dtype does not exist in `pandas` , and is wrapped around `datetime64[ns]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two concepts are quite different.

[`pandas.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) is a function that can take a variety of inputs and convert them to a pandas datetime index. For example:

```python
dates = pd.to_datetime([1610290846000000000, '2020-01-11', 'Jan 12 2020 2pm'])
print(dates)
# DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-10 15:00:46', '2020-01-11 00:00:00',
#                '2020-01-12 14:00:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

[`pandas.Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) is an interface on a pandas series that gives you convenient access to operations on data stored as a pandas datetime. For example:

```python
x = pd.Series(dates)
print(x.dt.date)
# 0    2021-01-10
# 1    2020-01-11
# 2    2020-01-12
# dtype: object

print(x.dt.hour)
# 0    15
# 1     0
# 2    14
# dtype: int64
```